# JavaScript is appending to a Div tag but with some strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a script that for every click of the button takes the time, applies @gmail.com to the end and appends it to a defined div tag.

where the problem lies is that every time i hit the button, the first line changes to the current time, an additional line is appended each time with the correct details and they don't update it is just the first line.

can someone suggest a way to stop the first line from updating each time?

```js
function Time() {
     var d = new Date();
     var dd = d.getDate();
     var mm = d.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
     var yy = d.getFullYear().toString().substr(2, 2);
     var j = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = dd + "" + mm + "" + yy + "" + d.getHours() + "" + d.getMinutes() + "" + d.getSeconds() + "@gmail.com<br />";

     $(document).ready(function() {
       $("button").click(function() {
         if (dd < 10) {
           dd = '0' + dd
         }
         if (mm < 10) {
           mm = '0' + mm
         }
         $("#demo").append(j);
       });
     });

     return j;

   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Click to generate time</h2>
    
    <button onclick="Time()">Generate</button>
    
    <div id="demo"></div>
```

What I expect to happen each time i press the button is for it to append the following:

2591695115@gmail.com
2591695116@gmail.com
2591695117@gmail.com
2591695118@gmail.com
...etc

Comment: @Teemu : I put the whole code in but it has been edited. the only thing missing is the html (where the first part is), title and body tag (where the div tag lies) what you see is the only javascript i have on the page

Comment: @t.niese there is the option to run the snippet, that shows what is happening better :-)

Comment: Yes, but it is not exactly clear to me what your expected result is. It would be easier to understand if you show the expected outcome.

Comment: @t.niese its similar to what is showing up, when you run the snippet. I have amended the question, hopefully that is more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `Time()` onclick in your HTML. You do not need to say  `$("button").click` again in your jquery.

Also, you do not need `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML` when assiging the string to `var j`.

See the following code:

```js
    
    function Time() {
     var d = new Date();
     var dd = d.getDate();
     var mm = d.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
     var yy = d.getFullYear().toString().substr(2, 2);
     var j = dd + "" + mm + "" + yy + "" + d.getHours() + "" + d.getMinutes() + "" + d.getSeconds() + "@gmail.com<br />";

        if (dd < 10) {
           dd = '0' + dd
         }
         if (mm < 10) {
           mm = '0' + mm
         }
         $("#demo").append(j);

     return j;

   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Click to generate time</h2>
    
    <button onclick="Time()">Generate</button>
    
    <div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work. The problem was the structure of your function. I took the button click outside of the `Time()` function and also changed `var j` to only declare the time instead of also already adding it to the HTML.

Also, by declaring `var j` after your `if` statements the date now displays correctly.

```js
function Time() {
     var d = new Date();
     var dd = d.getDate();
     var mm = d.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
     var yy = d.getFullYear().toString().substr(2, 2);

     if (dd < 10) {
        dd = '0' + dd
     }
     if (mm < 10) {
        mm = '0' + mm
     }

     var j = dd + "" + mm + "" + yy + "" + d.getHours() + "" + d.getMinutes() + "" + d.getSeconds() + "@gmail.com<br />";
     
     $("#demo").append(j);

   }

$("button").click(function() {
    Time();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Click to generate time</h2>
    
    <button>Generate</button>
    
    <div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: Just a small note: You don't need to use an additional anonymous function you can just write: `$("button").click(Test)`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to append the result from Time function.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        $("#demo").append(Time());
    });
});

function Time() {
    var d = new Date();
    var dd = d.getDate();
    var mm = d.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
    var yy = d.getFullYear().toString().substr(2, 2);
    var j = dd + "" + mm + "" + yy + "" + d.getHours() + "" + d.getMinutes() + "" + d.getSeconds() + "@gmail.com<br />";
    return j;
}
```

Comment: I was going for something like this originally, but had a function called append with the $("button").click(function () {....in it. However as i had't coded it right i thought it best to put it all in one function